# How to match *only* a six digit version?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

I am trying to match a six digit version (seperated by a dot `.` ),lets say `9.130.46.32.6.2` and it works fine but it matches a seven digit version (seperated by a dot `.`) aswell,lets say `9.130.46.32.6.2.1'`,how to ensure it only matches a six digit version but not anything else?

```
import re
version = '9.130.46.32.6.2' (six digit) -->SHOULD MATCH
version = '9.130.46.32.6.2.1'(seven digit) --> SHOULD NOT MATCH

#if the version is six digit append a ".0" as 4th digit

regex = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+')
m = regex.match(version)
if m:
    print "Its a six digit version..."
    digit1 = version.split('.')[-6]
    print digit1
    digit2 = version.split('.')[-5]
    print digit2
    digit3 = version.split('.')[-4]
    print digit3
    digit4 = version.split('.')[-3]
    print digit4
    digit5 = version.split('.')[-2]
    print digit5
    digit6 = version.split('.')[-1]
    print digit6
    new_version = digit1 + "."+ digit2 + "." + digit3 + "."+  "0." + digit4 + "." + digit5 + "." + digit6
print new_version
```

Comment: Please look up the difference between "digit" and "number". Hint: They behave like "letter" behaves to "word"

Comment: Also, what is the problem you are trying to solve ultimately? The code above doesn't give any context and I'm pretty sure you don't want any RegEx.

Comment: If it is not too late in your project, change to Python3! In particular its re librairy has some nice additions such as re.fullmatch that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `compile`, grab all digits in the IP and check its length:

```
import re
versions = ['9.130.46.32.6.2', '9.130.46.32.6.2.1']
new_versions = [i for i in versions if len(re.findall('\d+', i)) == 6]
```

Output:

```
['9.130.46.32.6.2']
```

Answer (score 2):

By anchoring the regex.

```
r'^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$'
```

Comment: `^\d+(\.\d+){5}$`

Answer (score 2):

```
# if the version is six numbers long insert a "0" as 4th number
fields = version.split(".")
if len(fields) == 6:
    fields = fields[0:3] + ["0"] + fields[3:6]

# `fields` now contains 7 numbers
print ".".join(fields)
```

Comment: This is probably the nicest approach for all situations where Ajax1234’s answer would work.

Comment: need to reconstruct fields to print the new version `9.130.46.0.32.6.2`,that would be a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
^([0-9]+\.){5}[0-9]+$
```

or using negative lookahead.

```
^([0-9]+\.){5}[0-9]+(?!\.\d+)
```

see: https://regex101.com/r/o0uNTy/1 and https://regex101.com/r/o0uNTy/2

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression match when using `re.match` can be any *prefix* of the string, so you’ll need to anchor it by matching the end of the string with `\Z`. (`$` is like `\Z` in Python regex, but can match a trailing newline.)

If you didn’t want to match the broader category of Unicode digits (like `١.٢.٣.٤.٥.٦`), you should probably also use `[0-9]`. Overall:

```
r"(?:[0-9]+\.){5}[0-9]+\Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

One other option would be to use a negative lookahead:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?!\.\d+)')
```

This would explicitly disallow a `.` followed by a sequence of digits from following your match.  This would mainly be interesting if you are trying to search through a string for the version numbers and wanted to match only the 6-part variant.

If you already have isolated the version as a string, however, anchoring is a more appropriate solution (or just split on `.` and don't use a regex at all).

Answer (score 0):

The method `re.match` will match any prefix of the string. If you are using *Python3*, use `re.fullmatch`, which will only match the full string instead. You can even use capturing groups to add `'.0'` as fourth digit.

```
version = '9.130.46.32.6.2'

regex = re.compile(r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)')

m = regex.fullmatch(version)

if m:
    new_version = m[1] + '.0' + m[2] # '9.130.46.0.32.6.2'
```

And here is an example for a seven digits version.

```
version = '9.130.46.32.6.2.1'

m = regex.fullmatch(version) # None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
import re
pattern=r'\d+'

print([re.findall(pattern,line) for line in open('text.txt','r') if len(re.findall(pattern,line))==6])
```

output:

```
[['9', '130', '46', '32', '6', '2']]
```